# Validation rule-only one person can uncheck a box

Tags: validation

I'm a very new admin and could use some help. Only admins should be able to uncheck a box. This is what I have but it's not quite right. Thank you!

```
AND(
    $Profile.Name <> "System Administrator",
    OR(
        AND(
            ISCHANGED(At_Risk__c),
            NOT(ISBLANK(PRIORVALUE(At_Risk__c)))
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I see two main things here. The usage of `OR()`, and how you're checking the previous value of your checkbox.

#### Boolean functions

The way you have your validation rule structured, the `OR()` is only operating on a single condition. It is technically correct syntax, but when you use `AND()` and `OR()`, you generally want to have them work on at least two conditions. The boolean operator functions also only operate on the stuff that's contained within the parenthesis.

So `OR(a, b, c)` in a Validation Rule is equivalent to `(a || b || c)` in the more standard way (i.e. the way most programmers are taught). Both are acceptable in a Validation Rule, but you should pick one and stick with it (don't mix and match within a Validation Rule or other formula). I personally prefer `AND()`, `OR()`, and `NOT()`.

At the end of the day, you don't need that `OR()` here. It shouldn't hurt, but it also doesn't help.

Getting rid of that `OR()` would leave you with something like `AND(x, AND(y, z))`. Since they're both `AND()` operations, they can be merged together, `AND(x, y, z)`.

One of the mantras of good software developers is "do as little typing/work as you can". This applies to formulas (like for Validation Rules) too, even if you don't think of yourself as a programmer. Why type more than you must? More typing = more chances to make a mistake.

#### Prior value of checkbox

Checkboxes cannot be null or blank when it comes to Validation Rules (they can be null in Apex, but must be either true or false to be able to be saved).

So instead of checking whether a checkbox `ISBLANK()`, you should be checking for true/false directly.
True = checked
False = unchecked

#### Putting that together

We arrive at something like this

```
AND(
    $Profile.Name <> "System Administrator",
    ISCHANGED(At_Risk__c),
    PRIORVALUE(At_Risk__c) = true
)
```

If `At_Risk__c` was previously checked, and it's changing (to the only other possible value, which is unchecked/false), and it's not being done by a sysadmin, this validation rule will complain and prevent the change from happening.

#### Bonus

If I really wanted to minimize the typing, it should be possible to reduce this further. `true = true` just results in `true`, so there should be no need for that equality check. Checkboxes only have two possible values, so if we know the prior value, we can simply check if the current value is different.

The minimal viable Validation Rule here would be

```
AND(
    $Profile.Name <> "System Administrator",
    NOT(At_Risk__c),
    PRIORVALUE(At_Risk__c)
)
```

I wouldn't go this far personally. Although it has become shorter (by 13 characters), I'd argue that this is harder to mentally process. If I came across this, I'd have to take extra time to figure out why this works and what it actually does.

This approach isn't normal (and it won't work for every field type), and things that aren't normal are harder for "the next guy" to maintain (and "the next guy" could absolutely be you, six months in the future after you've forgotten why you did this).

Comment: Very helpful!!! Thank you.

Comment: @JennyFlicker If your problem has been resolved, you should mark an answer as "accepted" (clicking the checkmark under the vote score). This gives you reputation score , it gives the answerer reputation score, and signals to the community that you don't need any additional help (and to other people with similar issues that the answer is likely to be good and work for them too). It's not mandatory, but it is part of the Stack Exchange culture.

Answer (score -1):

There are few changes to be made to above validation, Whenever you try to change 'At_Risk__c' field,  PRIORVALUE(At_Risk__c) checks if previous value of checkbox is true if yes this will trigger for non- admin profiles and using NOT condition will exclude Admin profile from validation.

Try below validation rule.

```
AND(
    ISCHANGED(At_Risk__c),
    PRIORVALUE(At_Risk__c) = true,
    NOT(
        $Profile.Name = "System Administrator"
    )
)
```

Also would suggest you to check few validation examples [here](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/latest/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_useful_validation_formulas.pdf).

Comment: Yes, but _why_ do you think this works? Giving the answer without giving an explanation isn't going to help OP learn what was wrong here (so they can hopefully avoid in in the future).

Comment: Thanks Derek, have included more details.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Cheers...…...:)